# Token missing in the request

Tags: java, json, rest, header, token

Here I'm trying to send the generated token from header to an API along with the data, but I'm getting an error:

> Token missing in the request

Not sure what's wrong with my code, can someone please guide me resolve this, thanks in advance.

```
String url = "API_TO_GENERATE_TOKEN"; 
                HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
                httpHeaders.set("CLIENT_ID", "VALUE_OF_CLIENTID");
                httpHeaders.set("CLIENT_SECRET", "VALUE_OF_CLIENT_SECRET");
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                HttpEntity <String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity <String> (json.toString(), httpHeaders);
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, httpEntity, String.class);
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
                System.out.println("Json Obj is:"+jsonObj);
                /*String balance = jsonObj.get("data").toString();
                System.out.println("Response is:"+response);*/
                JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
                String token = jsonObj1.getString("token");
                System.out.println("Token is " + token);        

                String url1=API_TO_ADD_USER";
                HttpHeaders httpHeaders1=new HttpHeaders();
                httpHeaders1.set("CLIENT_ID", "VALUE_OF_CLIENT_ID");
                httpHeaders1.set("CLIENT_SECRET", "VALUE_OF_CLIENT_SECRET");
                httpHeaders1.set("Content-Type","application/json");
                httpHeaders1.set("Authorization","Bearer"+token);

//              JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();

                Filter u= new Filter();


                u.setName("my_name");
                u.setPhone("123456789");
                u.setVendorId("P1234");
                u.setAddress1("my_address1");
                u.setAddress2("my_address2");
                u.setCity("my_city");
                u.setState("my_state");
                u.setEmail("myemail@abc.com");

                HttpEntity<Filter> httpEntity1 = new HttpEntity<>(u, httpHeaders1);
                RestTemplate restTemplate1 = new RestTemplate();
                //String response1 = restTemplate1.postForObject(url1, httpEntity1, String.class);

                ResponseEntity<String> response1 = restTemplate.postForEntity(url1, httpEntity1, String.class);

//              JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(response1);
                System.out.println("Json Obj111 is:"+response1);
```

Comment: Do you need a space after "Bearer" ie "Bearer " on your Authorization header value

Comment: @markusrambarkus Yes you are rite, it's working fine after adding a space, thanks a ton..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue while using RestClient by not separating "Bearer" & Token with space, so I would go `httpHeaders1.set("Authorization","Bearer "+token)` and you should be fine.